# How update a serialized column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

there is a big model with a serialized column

```
serialize :places
```

There are several places stored.

```
City.all.first.places
=> "[school, libary, store, flowers, bank]"
```

I want to delete all flowers, and rename 'store' to 'warehouse'
If there is a 'store', there should be also a 'church'

I created following task, but the data are the same if I check some entries.

```
City.all.each do |city|
  next unless city.places.present?
  places = city.places[1..-2].split(', ')
  places.delete('flowers')
  if places.include?('store')
    places.delete('store')
    places.push('warehouse','church')
  end
  city.places = places 
  city.save
end
```

Comment: Try to break this down into a *minimal* problem. `city.places = ["school", "libary", "bank", "warehouse", "church"]; city.save` <-- Does this fail? Why? Check `city.errors`.

Comment: You serialized column is already an array, so there is no need to use `split`. Try this in console: `City.all.first.places.class`, you'll get `=> Array` (BTW, you can skip `all` and go directly to `first`).

Comment: And city.places[1..-2].split(', ') isn't probably doing what you want it. A better way would be to strip the string of all white spaces (if they can only come after a comma) city.places.gsub(/\s+/, "").split(',') or only white spaces that come after a comma like city.places.gsub(', ', ',').split(',')

Comment: @TomLord The message is empty, and in base is the object.
.

Comment: @Garry no, the class is "string" so I cannot change it directly. If I add 'Array' after the serialize command, the column is getting empty

Comment: @RickySpanish So if `city.places = ...; city.save` **WORKS**, then what exactly is your error?!

Comment: @TomLord The problem is that after the saving city.places isn't updated

Comment: Let's get this clear... A minimal, reproducible example of your problem is: `puts city.places  => <original>; city.places = <new>; city.save => true; city.places => <original>` ???!!!!

Comment: @RickySpanish How do you set the value in `places` when  you first create the record?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should have places be it's own table and then have a join table to connect them to cities like:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :city_places
  has_many :places, through: :city_places
end

class CityPlace < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :place
end

class Places < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :city_places
  has_many :cities, through: :city_places
end
```

That way cities can have many places and if you ever want to rename a place you can just change it's name in the database. Here are [the docs for this kind of relationship in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).